# DateTime Column Set to Past Date

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a SQL Server database for storing our transaction data. In each of the table, we have a `LastUpdatedOn` column which gets populated by using the `GETDATE()` function.

What we are seeing is when we have bulk update operations on these tables, at the end of bulk operation, the timestamp in the `LastUpdatedOn` column will be past date.

Eg: if the update operation started at time 10:00:00.000 AM, the `GETDATE()` function will select that as the time and the `LastUpdatedOn` column will be populated with datetime as 10:00:00.000 AM. If the script takes 30 seconds to execute, the at 10:00:30.000 AM, when the scripts completes the executed, the `lastupdateon` column will be populated with a past date.

See the sample script below:

```
SELECT TOP 100000 * 
INTO #tmp 
FROM dbo.Test

BEGIN TRAN

UPDATE L
SET l.lastupdateon = getdate()
FROM dbo.Test L
JOIN #tmp T ON T.entitykey = L.entitykey

COMMIT TRAN
```

The issue which we are running into is, we have a delta operation that has from and to dates. This operation will return any records that got updated between the from and to date. In this case, if delta operation gets called at 10:00:15.000 AM, the records that got updated as a part of the script will not be pulled even though the record got updated at 10:00:00.000 AM. These records will never get pulled.

Is there any solution for this problem other than making the transaction serializable?

Regards,

John

Comment: Could you paste your stored procedure or method that bulk inserts records to the question?

Comment: @AbdullahNehir: It is a simple update statement. But still i have added the script as well.

Comment: Could you assign a variable that stores when the query executes, and then when the query ends assign another variable with the current time, get the difference between the two and then add it to your LastUpdatedOn field?

Comment: actually you don't have any records updated at the 10:00:00.000 AM, they all updatet at 10:00:30.000 AM. Phisically the records may not be inserted in a sorting you mean.

Comment: @xdd: But the date time stamp refers to 10:00:00.000 AM. That is incorrect, rite?

Comment: Can you delay your delta operation, so that instead of using a range up to "Now", it has a range up to "5 minutes ago", so that it will never look for rows that might still be updating?

Comment: @TabAlleman: That may not be possible as the delta should be able to give the real time updates

Comment: That is incorrect, rite? - no, the major thing is - that all records have the same time. GetDate called one time - this is logic of SQL-server.

Comment: @xdd: Yes. that could be how any SQL engines work. But is there a way which i can work around?

Comment: another way to "solve" your problem is to update rows one at a time.  Though this merely trades it for another problem.

Comment: As you said, serializable could solve this by making the delta operation block inserts when reading and to be blocked when something is inserting. "These records will never get pulled." is not quite true. They will be picked up if you do the delta operation again, after the transaction ended over the same interval.

Comment: Your problem is with the logic you have in the delta operation not with the insert statement. `lastupdateon` will always have a past date when the transaction ends no matter how you do it (unless you update with a future time) and there will always be a race condition between the delta operation and the commit of the transaction no matter how fast your inserts and commit are.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson: How best i can change the delta operation so that i will get all the changes?

Comment: One option could be to make sure it only processes records well in the past and no way near the current time. How far back depends on how long time your update transactions take. It really depends on what it is supposed to do. Perhaps you can execute consecutively it with overlapping intervals and handle the cases where you get rows you have already seen.

Comment: If you only want to see any one row once you could have an [output clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql) on the update and add the modified rows to second table and the delta operation can pick rows from that table and delete them when done.

Comment: @Mikael: how about changing the request parameters for delta from date time stamp to database version number?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. Did you mean to generate a version number from a [sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql) and use that number to mark all modified rows with the same number? And then the delta operation needs to keep track of last used version number and get the previous version number from the sequence. Would still be a race condition against the current number you get from the sequence. You could have multiple update statements running at the same time where first started finishes after one that is started later.

Comment: Remember that rows are not visible to the delta operation until they are committed. Unless you do dirty reads but then you might get rows that will never be committed. Probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental problem is that the update takes time, so there will always be a delay between when you tell SQL Server to write a value to the table and when that value is committed and visible to others.

You need to address this in your delta operation.  Is only one process writing to the table?  If so, newly committed rows will always have a LastUpdatedOn value that is after everything else in the table.  In this case, the delta operation should keep track of the max LastUpdatedOn value it got last time and look for anything greater than that.